# Syntax for const accessor by reference

Tags: c++, constants, accessor

Right now my implementation returns the thing by value. The member `m_MyObj` itself is not `const` - its value changes depending on what the user selects with a Combo Box. I am no C++ guru, but I want to do this right. If I simply stick a `&` in front of `GetChosenSourceSystem` in both decl. and impl., I get one sort of compiler error. If I do one but not another - another error. If I do `return &m_MyObj;`. I will not list the errors here for now, unless there is a strong demand for it. I assume that an experienced C++ coder can tell what is going on here. I could omit constness or reference, but I want to make it tight and learn in the process as well.

```
// In header file
MyObj GetChosenThingy() const;

// In Implementation file.
MyObj MyDlg::GetChosenThingy() const
{
    return m_MyObj;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The returned object will have to be const, so you cant change it from outside;

```
// In header file
const MyObj& GetChosenThingy() const;

// In Implementation file.
const MyObj& MyDlg::GetChosenThingy() const
{
    return m_MyObj;
}
```

Comment: Another thing to keep in mind. If, as I assume, m_MyObj is a data member of MyDlg, make sure that the reference isn't kept around any longer that the object that returned it.  If you try to access a member of an object that has been deleted, nothing good can happen.

Comment: Also, would you please elaborate which const does what?

Comment: @Hamish: The const to the left says that the returned MyObj& is const, and cant be modified.The const to the right says that the class MyDlg is'nt modified in any way when the function GetChosenThingy() is executed.